# OpenGL Android API source

Tags: android, opengl-es

On the [Android Developers' Graphics page](http://source.android.com/devices/graphics.html), it states:

> Note that the OpenGL API exposed to app developers is different from the OpenGL interface that you are implementing. Apps do not have access to the GL driver layer, and must go through the interface provided by the APIs.

How does Android differentiate the API calls from the GL driver code? Where does it implement the OpenGL API in the Android source code?

Comment: Reminds me a little bit of the hardware abstraction layer in D3D... as an application developer it is your job to pretend like this stuff does not exist :) You are expected not to think about anything lower-level than application-layer GL API, since it is out your control. Like chemists whose jobs would be immensely more complicated if suddenly they had to think about (theorteical) sub-atomic particles; leave that to the physicists and do your job :P

Comment: I agree that it's unnecessary to know from an application developer standpoint. However, just because I don't need to know something doesn't mean I shouldn't bother learning it if I'm interested.

Comment: I suspect what is being talked about here is the EGL window system layer. A similar protocol which is actually sort of documented in a way that non-licensed developers can implement is described in glX. Since you're not writing drivers for an Android device you'll never have a chance to implement the EGL protocol.